# Angular 7 Http.get() returns Internal Server Error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get the data from Asp.net Core Web API. The API works fine and returns data in the browser and in postman too while testing. But whenever I'm trying to call it from my angular application it returns Internal Server Error (500). How can I get data in angular and log it to console?

API Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]        
[EnableCors]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetValues()
{
    try
    {
        var values = await _context.Values.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(values);
    }
    catch (Exception _ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(_ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Angular Code:

```js
getValues() {
    this.httpClient.get('https://localhost:5001/api/values').subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Inside the network tab of the browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6iw5.png

Comment: You might need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on server side.

Comment: Do you mean CORS? I've already added CORS in Startup.cs file    Inside Configure function :                                                   app.UseCors(x=> x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());

Comment: Can You please check what is exactly being logged in network tab in your browser developer tools? Please share it here

Comment: I've edited my question with the image of the network tab from my browser.

Comment: I can not find any request to my API URL inside the network tab.

Comment: @Rohit_Chiki Make sure you have imported the `httpClient` from the correct package!!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan                                                                                                   In my Component File:                                                                               
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';                                                      
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

Comment: @Rohit_Chiki, can you able to set debugger point in your server side controller?

Comment: @Emdad Yes, I am able to set debugged point and it gets hit whenever I try to call the API

Comment: Do you get any errors displayed in the browser debug console? Can you show the HTTP request made by the angular app on the network tab?

Comment: Can you show the full component code showing how you actually call your API?